# In python, why import 'object' from builtins module?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In order to transition to python 3, I am trying to understand writing python 2 and python 3 compatible codes. The following code is from `python-future.org` and illustrates a way to construct an iterator that would be compatible with both versions of python.

```
from builtins import object

class Upper(object):
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self._iter = iter(iterable)
    def __next__(self):      # Py3-style iterator interface
        return next(self._iter).upper()  # builtin next() function calls
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

itr = Upper('hello')
assert next(itr) == 'H'      # compatible style
assert list(itr) == list('ELLO')
```

The code runs fine in python 2, but to my surprise, if i remove the import statement then i get an error `TypeError: Upper object is not an iterator`. I often derive my custom classes from `object` but i have never imported it from builtins. Why does simply importing `object` change the behaviour of the code?

Comment: Python 2 requires `builtins` to be pip-installed. It's designed for writing code compatible on Python 2 and 3.

Comment: When *I* run this code in Python 2, I get `ImportError: No module named builtins`.  There *is* a module named `__builtin__`, and I can do `from __builtin__ import object`, but it makes no difference, I get the `TypeError: Upper object is not an iterator` either way.  Which makes sense, because in Python 2 you implement `next`, not `__next__`, to be an iterator.  I think the code sample you are reading is just wrong.  Could you please post a direct link to it?  Also please tell us exactly which versions of Python 2 and 3 you are testing with.

Comment: So there is a difference between the ``object`` available in the default namespace and the one that is imported from ``builtins``?

Comment: @OrangeFlash81 Oh, `builtins` is another forward-compatibility bolt-on like `six`?  I'm not finding it on PyPI, where do you get it?

Comment: @zwol http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html#custom-iterators

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are (indirectly) importing from the [`future.builtins` module](http://python-future.org/reference.html#module-future.builtins); it provides a *custom* `object` baseclass that adds forward-pointing special names.

In Python 2, iterators must have a [`next()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter) (as well as `__iter__`); this method was renamed to [`__next__` in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter). By not using the `future.builtins.object` version you are simply missing the `next` -> `__next__` alias provided in Python 2.

See the [source code for `future.types.newobject.py`](https://github.com/PythonCharmers/python-future/blob/master/src/future/types/newobject.py#L69-L72):

> ```
> def next(self):
>     if hasattr(self, '__next__'):
>         return type(self).__next__(self)
>     raise TypeError('newobject is not an iterator')
> ```

Note that `builtins` will return standard built-in objects if you are running Python 3, the module only returns shims like these for Python 2.

You could simply add that same alias yourself:

```
class Upper(object):
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self._iter = iter(iterable)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):      # Py3-style iterator interface
        return next(self._iter).upper()  # builtin next() function calls
    next = __next__          # Py2 alias
```