# Import or not to import classmethod?

Tags: python, python-import, class-method

I hope this isn't a stupid question but I found some code where they imported `classmethod` and some code where they don't so there is difference?

I'm using python 3.6 but the code originally I think was for python 2.7 (it used `from __builtin__ import`)

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from builtins import classmethod #original code was from __builtin__ import classmethod 


class HomePageTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUp(cls):
        # create a new Firefox session
        cls.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        cls.driver.maximize_window()

        # navigate to the application home page
        cls.driver.get("http://demo-store.seleniumacademy.com/")

    def test_search_field(self):
        pass

    #My tests without @classmethod

    @classmethod
    def tearDown(cls):
        # close the browser window
        cls.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

Comment: is this a question?

Comment: @MEdwin it is, and I am quite interested in knowing the answer :)

Comment: @MEdwin Yes, I'm asking if there is difference, which one, if there was in python 2.7 but not anymore, if I should import or not, etc... The code comes from a book so maybe there was some motive if they do that, isnt just random code you find somewhere in internet

Comment: [This SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36517648/in-python-why-import-object-from-builtins-module) might give you a meaningful explanation.

Comment: @bro-grammer sorry maybe I wasn't enough clear but the code from the book was `from __builtin__ import classmethod`, I changed in  `from builtins import classmethod` because Python 3 changed the name of the module `__builtin__` in `builtins`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally you only import `builtins` or `__builtin__` if you also have a variable in your code with the same name as a builtin and also want to access the builtin name. The documentation of the module explains it rather well:

> ### [builtins — Built-in objects](https://docs.python.org/library/builtins.html)
>
> This module provides direct access to all ‘built-in’ identifiers of Python; for example, `builtins.open` is the full name for the built-in function `open()`. See [Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#built-in-funcs) and [Built-in Constants](https://docs.python.org/library/constants.html#built-in-consts) for documentation.
>
> This module is not normally accessed explicitly by most applications, but can be useful in modules that provide objects with the same name as a built-in value, but in which the built-in of that name is also needed. For example, in a module that wants to implement an `open()` function that wraps the built-in `open()`, this module can be used directly:
>
> ```
> import builtins
>
> def open(path):
>     f = builtins.open(path, 'r')
>     return UpperCaser(f)
>
> class UpperCaser:
>     '''Wrapper around a file that converts output to upper-case.'''
>
>     def __init__(self, f):
>         self._f = f
>
>     def read(self, count=-1):
>         return self._f.read(count).upper()
> ```

However in your case there seems to be no `classmethod` definition in the file so you don't actually need the `from builtins import classmethod`.

Answer (score -1):

In Python 3, there's no need to import the `builtins` module, or anything inside it. When the lookup for a name in the current scope fails, `builtins` is looked up as a fallback.

If you need to maintain code integrity, consider explicitly checking Python version before this.

```py
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    from __builtin__ import classmethod
```

Comment: yes, pls correct that to *in Python*, which would be quite correct. however, having 3 as a qualifier is very misleading in my opinion.  there’s enough 2 vs 3 upgrade angst without adding undue worries.  one thing that can happen is that 3’s builtins don’t include all of 2’s functions, **cmp** for example.  **classmethod**?  nope that exists in both.